# Firebase queryEqual to any of multiple values

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm writing a chat app using a Firebase database. I need to query my data to find the messages to show to the user. I am currently using `queryEqual` to find all the posts FROM the specified user:

```
databaseRef.child("posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "uid").queryEqual(toValue: FirebaseManager.currentUser?.uid)
```

This returns all the posts sent from the logged in user, but doesn't return anything sent TO the logged in user. I can get the messages sent to the logged in user by changing 'uid' to 'toId' as follows:

```
databaseRef.child("posts").queryOrdered(byChild: "toId").queryEqual(toValue: FirebaseManager.currentUser?.uid)
```

But how can I combine the two into one query that says "give me all the posts where either 'uid' or 'toId' is equal to this value"?

Here is my database:

[image: database]

Comment: You mean fetch ALL the posts (from and to anyone) and filter them on the client side?

Comment: Please look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26701282/5065318